# Create GCP project using resourcemanager API in python

Tags: python, django, google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to create Google cloud project using ResourceManager API python client but not success.

Here's what I have tried:

1. Setup gcloud
2. RUN gcloud beta auth application-default login to setup credentials
3. also setup service account
4. Enable resource manager api from GCP console.

Here's my python code:
**From views.py**

```
from google.cloud import resource_manager
...

# GCP Client
client = resource_manager.Client()
# List down all gcp projects
for project in client.list_projects():
    print(project)
# Create a new project
client.new_project(project_id='test-123', name='api')
```

it list down all of my GCP projects but new project doesn't created on my gcp console.

Also it doesn't return any error.

Help me, please!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Successfully managed to create google cloud project by using Google cloud API python client.

**Steps**

- run gcloud beta auth application-default login command to get application default credentials by login onto the browser
- Enable Resource Manager API on my gcp console

Here's the working python code:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
...


credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
    service = discovery.build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
            project_body = {
                'name': 'Api Project',
                'projectId': 'api-9837'
            }
            request = service.projects().create(body=project_body)
            request.execute()
            pprint(request)
```